# Cannot find instructions to read .dmp file with Symbol file using Google Breakpad

Tags: node.js, node-webkit

I am using node-webkit for a WebGL application on Ubuntu 12.10

The node is crashing and generating a .dmp file. I want to understand what's going on and have followed below steps

1. Downloaded Google Breakpad
2. From console ran

./google-breakpad-read-only/src/processor/minidump_stackwalk /tmp/chromium-renderer-minidump-361d8469dbb05de4.dmp

which gives me output but I am unable to understand it. Apparently interpreting it with a symbol file will help.

The node-webkit github wiki includes a symbol file (https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Crash-dump)

I am not sure how to use the symbol file to interpret the dmp file with minidump_stackwalk.

Have looked long and hard and cannot find any instructions on how to do it.

If someone can help it will be really awesome.

Thanks